# copy word doc footer to excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to get the footer text in a MS_Word Doc with an excel macro and paste it into an excel sheet. this VBA code works in MS_WORD  but NOT in MS_EXCEL macro. I checked and the section count = 1 in the document.

```
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim h As Object 'Word.HeaderFooter
Dim docver As String 'Paste this to excel

Set wdDoc = GetObject("D:docname.docx")

With wdDoc

    For Each h In .Sections

        docver = h.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text

    Next

End With
```

Comment: Check out this article about [Opening Word Documents from Excel VBA](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d543bf7f-49f0-4192-a050-e582ed47ced2/opening-a-word-document-from-an-excel-vba-module?forum=isvvba).  There are some points in there about setting the object that you will want to see.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use the "watch window" under the VBA project view to determine the Syntax structure. the correct syntax is as follows:

For Each h In .Sections.Item.Footers

```
docver = h.Footers.Item(1).Range.Text
```

Next

Comment: Kudos for answering your own question.  The Locals window can be pretty helpful as well.  It's just like the watch window, except it shows all the variables that are contained in the scope of the module you are working in.  Also, the immediate window can provide instant feedback on any variable's current state.

Answer (score -1):

```
how to I extract a footer for each document. It is only finding the footer for the first document. 

Currently my code is 

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim docvers As String

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("U:\word" & "\")
i = 1
strDirectory = "U:\word" & "\"

varDirectory = Dir(strDirectory, vbNormal)
docvers = strDirectory & varDirectory

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim h As Object 'Word.HeaderFooter
Dim docver As String 'Paste this to excel

Set wdDoc = GetObject(docvers)

With wdDoc

For Each h In .Sections

        docver = h.footers.Item(2).Range.Text

    Next

End With
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
 'print file name
 Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
'print file path
 Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Path
 Cells(i + 1, 3) = docver

 i = i + 1
Next objFile
```

Comment: “This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation.”